# Why did Hinzelmann owe a debt to Mr. Wednesday?

Tags: american-gods

In chapter 20 of Neil Gaiman's *American Gods*, Hinzelman says that he saved Shadow's life because he owes a debt to Mr. Wednesday.  Do we know why he owes this debt?  Is it explained somewhere in the book?

Comment: Damn good question. I don't know the answer :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing in the book to explain it.

> *Hinzelmann tipped his head on one side. He scratched his nose, thoughtfully, rocked back and forth as if he were thinking. “Well,” he said. “That’s a good question. I guess it’s because I owed a certain party a debt. And I’m good for my debts.”
>
>   “Wednesday?”
>
>   “That’s the fellow.”*

And that's all that's said about it.

---

Given that their personal histories go back nearly a millennium, it's quite likely that they've encountered each other repeatedly. Wednesday is, of course an inveterate hustler, a trader of information and collector of favours. It's not until later in the novel that we realise that he's been setting up *a network of safe-houses* to allow him to stash Shadow away from his enemies.

> *“Initially, simply the pleasure of your company. And I have
>   information to share. What’s that phrase…oh yes. **You may learn
>   something to your advantage."***

and

> *Their breath steamed in the night air. Christmas lights twinkled in the windows of the stores they passed. “It’s good of you, putting me up,” said Shadow. “I appreciate it.”
>
>   **“We owe your employer a number of favors** [Said Mr. Ibis].  And Lord knows, we have the room. It’s a big old house. There used to be more of us, you know. Now it’s just the three of us. You won’t be in the way.”*

Comment: Good point about collecting favours. For all we know, he might owe the favour to _another_ Odin, from his time in Germany.